# Jest testing error: Unexpected token <

Tags: reactjs, testing, jsx, jestjs

Im trying to test my components with Jest.
I believe that I've installed all the required modules to run the tests.
Last thing that I did was to run

`yarn add -D babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs`.

This is my code while trying to do a simple Jest test:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Market from '../src/components/Market.js';

test('Market should render as expected', () => {
  const component = shallow(<Market />);
  console.log(component);
});
```

The error message on the console points to the first `<` at the start of invoking the Market component on line 6.

Comment: show your babel config

Comment: Have you installed `babel-jest`?

Comment: already installed babel-jest.
i used create-react-app; so the babel config is automatic.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Adding transform or anything didn't fix it. So i finally added .babelrc file and added following configuration and it worked.

```
 {
    "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
 }
```

Hope this will help you.